# T-SQL enum number or string

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, enums

I have a table `Drivers` with columns `Id`, `Name`, `Status`. In C# I have an enum for driver status

```
public enum DriverStatus
{
   Online = 0,
   Offline = 1,
   Busy = 2,
   SoonFree = 3
}
```

Currently in the database, I use a `varchar` data type for the `Status` column and this means I have records like:

```
1     John      Online
2     Elsy      Offline
```

This seams to be bad and I think this need to be changed to status column type `tinyint` because:

1. T-SQL `Tinyint` is only one byte size with range 0-255.
2. Now it is not possible to normally sort by status column because it is `varchar` so it sorts in alphabetical order not in enum priorities.
3. If I rename `DriverStatus` enum value name I also need to update database to be consistent.

Then I asked others why we use `varchar` for enum columns the only reason was that it is easier to debug as you see text not number like 0 or 3. Is where any really good reasons to have strings for enums in the database?

Comment: Yeah, their reasons are really good.  It's easier to understand the data.  If you're a future developer or report-creator, how else will you know what the values mean?  If you really need them to sort, then use a CASE WHEN to translate them in your view.  I definitely don't think the only reason you'd choose a numeric value over a textual value for lookups is for sorting purposes.

Comment: You *could* have another table in the database which relates `StatusCode` to `StatusDescription`. You don't have to actually use it, but it would be there for someone to see.

Comment: Possible solutions: 1) Open C# entity class which represents database table and look at described enum of cores if you have it. 2) If it is pure database project there can be separate table for enum key value, then report creator can join it to get user friendly value.

Comment: Wow I misread that at first and thought it was combining all that data in one column. Storing it in its string form is acceptable depending on its use. Why don't you ask one of the previous devs what the table etc is being used for.

Comment: @rory.ap are you suggesting they shouldn't use a lookup table for this sort of thing? Sticking text over and over in rows is not a good practice at all. I would not use the number for sorting though. Also, consider what happens when you need to change the text value. You have to update the whole table. Ugh!!!

Comment: @SeanLange -- Yes, definitely.  I've seen plenty of examples of this with many different software vendors.  If you combine it with a constraint, it works wonderfully and is self-documenting.  And if you need to change the text value, you did something wrong in the design phase.  Enums, by their nature, shouldn't change.

Comment: Agreed they shouldn't change but that doesn't change the very real fact that the spelling can change as business changes over time. From a database perspective I would not like this because it is not normalized. It of course can work and has worked many times. I would prefer to use a lookup table. I don't agree it makes the data more difficult to understand, you just have to look in another table like we do with so many other values that are properly normalized. But being an enum it brings some addition caveats to the table for sure. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely better to use a Lookup Table for enum values.

Advantages:

- Usually less room in the database is used.
- Renaming the display value is very easy.
- Globalization is possible.
- It is easy to retire values that are no longer used.

  - My lookup tables always contain three fields:  [the ID/Primary Key], Name, and Enabled